# Can not found Row 0 in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I try to select the first row and first item from my SQL 
But, it show me message "Can not found Row 0 "

```
sqlCmd1 = "SELECT Type.Name FROM Type INNER JOIN Room ON Type.TID = Room.TypeID WHERE (((Room.ROID)= " + (roomCB.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString() + "));"
ad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd1, cnn)
ds = New DataSet
ad.Fill(ds)
Try
    typeTxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You've tried running your SQL statement in the database to see that actually produces a result?

Comment: **1.** Have you checked the result of your query? Have you made sure that it *always* returns at least one record? **2.** What is the *actual*, exact error message? (**3.** Consider using a parameterized query instead of doing dynamic SQL.)

Comment: yes I used this SQL in Query and I get the result

Comment: If you take out the combo box value, hard code a known `Room.ROID` value into the select statement what happens?

Comment: The query is work in Access but the problem is in how to set the value to TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Why are you filling a DataTable if you want to retrieve just a single field?
`ExecuteScalar` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Also you should use parameterized query in order to avoid SQL Injection.

Off the top of my head...

```
Dim RoomID As String = roomCB.SelectedIndex + 1.ToString()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Type.Name FROM Type INNER JOIN Room ON Type.TID = @parameter"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = RoomID
        typeTxt.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        cn.Close()
    End Using
```